# VBS script to list interface and MAC

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make simple script that show computer name, logged user name, IP address, and ethernet interface (wired ) name and it's MAC:

```
intCount = 0
strMAC   = ""
' We're interested in MAC addresses of physical adapters only
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID > ''"

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
Set colItems      = objWMIService.ExecQuery( strQuery, "WQL", 48 )

For Each objItem In colItems
If objItem.AdapterType = "Ethernet 802.3" then
If InStr( strMAC, objItem.MACAddress ) = 0 Then
    strMAC   = strMAC & ", " & objItem.MACAddress
    Name = objItem.Name & vbCRLF
    intCount = intCount + 1
End If
End If
Next

' Remove leading comma
If intCount > 0 Then strMAC = Mid( strMAC, 2 )
dim NIC1, Nic, StrIP, CompName
Set NIC1 = 
GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
For Each Nic in NIC1
if Nic.IPEnabled then
StrIP = Nic.IPAddress(i)
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim objNetwork
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
CompName = WshNetwork.Computername
Dim WMI, Configs, Config, Adapters, Adapter
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}root/cimv2")

strUserName = wshNetwork.UserName

MsgBox "IP Adres: "&StrIP & vbNewLine _
& "Computer Name: "&CompName & vbNewLine _
& "Login: "&strUserName & vbNewLine _
& "Interface and MAC: "& Name, & strMAC ,4160,"Information about  IP"

 wscript.quit
 end if
 next
```

but it's not working, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Set NIC1 = 
GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
```

to one line

```
Set NIC1 = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
```

and remove the , here:

```
& "Interface and MAC: "& Name, & strMAC ,4160,"Information about  IP"
```

==>

```
& "Interface and MAC: "& Name & strMAC ,4160,"Information about  IP"
```